# ros with open cv

Tags: ros, opencv, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im trying to create a ros package with an open cv program , but while doing a rosmake command i get an error
error while loading shared libraries: libcv_bridge.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ive installed the vision open cv for ros. is there anything that im missing ?
do i have to install the actual open cv headers ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11878/ros-with-open-cv/) by [vivek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1350/vivek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-11-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The preferred method for linking against opencv is now to use cmake in your package directly.

See: http://www.ros.org/wiki/opencv2#OpenCV_in_Electric

If the problem still persists, then you might have another problem.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2011-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4